# Conceptually understanding Preloading of Images

Tags: jquery

I have two code snippets with me

```
// Code Snippet One
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

preload([
    'img/One.jpg',
    'img/Two.jpg',
    'img/Three.jpg'
]);​

// Code Snippet Two
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
        $('<img />').attr('src',this).appendTo('body').hide();
});
```

1. How do I use the code to make sure the images have preloaded before using them?
2. How to fire a notification that says all images have been preloaded. Any new jQuery 1.8 functionality that I can use here?
3. What's is the difference between Code Snippet One and Two. Which to use when?

A fiddle example is most appreciated

Here's how I am trying to load the preloaded images in a div (image-gallery)

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $('.image-gallery').each(function(){
            // what to put here?
        });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example will create an image element in memory and change its src to point to your image to be preloaded. The problem is that some browser (versions) do not start to load the images unless they have been added to the DOM. That's what snippet two is doing.

In both cases you could add a `.load()` event handler to the jQuery image object to specify a callback for when the respective image has been loaded.

Try to use a counter. You increase the counter in each .load() handler and if it reached your image count, all images have finished loading.

EDIT: Change snippet two like this

```
function preload(arrayOfImages, callback) {
    var counter = 0;    
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
        $('<img />').load(function() {
            counter++;
            if(counter==arrayOfImages.length) callback();
        }).attr('src',this).appendTo('body').hide();
    });
}
```

And call it like this

```
preload([
'img/One.jpg',
'img/Two.jpg',
'img/Three.jpg'
], function() {
    // what should happen when all of the images have been loaded
    $('<img />').attr('src', 'img/Two.jpg').appendTo('.image-gallery');
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will go with Snippet Two, but how do I test it? I want to load these images in a random DIV for example.

Comment: Just add an <img> element to your DIV and apply one of the src you previously preloaded and it should appear immediately in the DIV (with no additional loading delay)

Comment: I have updated the question with an example. Can you tell me what to fill there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the Jquery [Load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). It is deprecated but no one's come up with a better replacement. It will basically do what you want though.

> As soon as the image has been loaded, the handler is called.

Comment: There is no mention on the jQuery API that the .load() event handler is deprecated ... so feel free to use it http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: ooh yeah this is strange ... what to use instead? Usually the API would tell you inside the description that's why I failed to see it